# Delete special character SOH with RegExp

Tags: vba, regexp-replace

For an Access development I used GetOpenFilename function as explained [here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d1088227/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/getopenfilename-filtre-d-apres-nom-d-fichier/#post6021744)
But lpstrTitle is set with special character SOH. To delete SOH, I create a regExp function

```
Public Function RegParse(sStr As String) '----> sStr is lpstrTitle from getopenfiled 

Dim oRegex As New RegExp

sPattern = "^.*?(?=\x01)"  '--> Failed on .Test   
'sPattern = ^[^\x01]*  '--> successful.Test but SOH still there
'sPattern = (^.*)v(.*)  '-->Ok but  v deleted  
.Replace(sStr, "$1")

With oRegex 
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .pattern = sPattern
    .Global = False

    If .Test(sStr) Then
     sStr1 = .Execute(sStr)(0) 

End With

End Function
```

But sStr1 is still with SOH characters with sPattern = ^[^\x01]*

And command sStr1 = .replace(sStr1, “$1”) is impossible because sPattern = "^.*?(?=\x01) failed in .test

Thanks by advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the special characters are not chr(1) but chr(0) or x00
I tested with this function

```
Public Function mfShowChar(psStr As String)
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim arrChar() As Integer

  For i = 1 To Len(psStr)
     ReDim Preserve arrChar(i)
     ArrChar(i) = Asc(Mid(psStr, i)) 
  Next

 End Function
```

And the both solutions work

- sStr = Replace(typOpenFile.lpstrFile, Chr(0), vbNullString)
- RegExp but with sPattern = "(^.*?(?=\x00))(\x00*)"

Answer (score 3):

Just do a simple find and replace with nothing if you want to remove a specific character:

```
sStr1 = Replace(sStr1, Chr(1), "", Compare := vbBinaryCompare)
```

`vbBinaryCompare` makes the find and replace binary, to avoid weirdness with control characters.

Comment: I tried sFileName = Replace(typOpenFile.lpstrFile, Chr(1), "", Compare:=vbBinaryCompare) but no success. SOH characters are not deleted

Comment: That's very hard to believe if they're true SOH characters... Please try to provide a [mre]

Comment: hu Erik, first thanks again for your help. Click on this [link](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2002105/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/regexp-suppression-caraceres-soh/) and upload the New1.txt file for an example

Comment: That doesn't help me. My function is able to strip the SOH characters from that just fine. I did notice a typo (= should be :=), but the answer should just work

Comment: Please share the code on-site. Edit the question to demonstrate the whole issue. Also, I strongly recommend using the unicode equivalent functions. ANSI functions tend to have weird issues with strings.

Comment: I added RegExp Tester screencopies still [here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2002105/logiciels/microsoft-office/excel/macros-vba-excel/regexp-suppression-caraceres-soh/#post11114221) which confirm correct regExp

Comment: Yes, please, with an English explanation. I don't like visiting random foreign sites.

Comment: Replace fonction didn't work for me. SOH characters are still in the string.

Answer (score 0):

My code in a module

```
Public Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

Public Type OPENFILENAME
lStructSize       As Long
hwndOwner         As Long
hInstance         As Long
lpstrFilter       As String
lpstrCustomFilter As String
nMaxCustFilter    As Long
nFilterIndex      As Long
lpstrFile         As String
nMaxFile          As Long
lpstrFileTitle    As String
nMaxFileTitle     As Long
lpstrInitialDir   As String
lpstrTitle        As String
flags             As Long
nFileOffset       As Integer
nFileExtension    As Integer
lpstrDefExt       As String
lCustData         As Long
lpfnHook          As Long
lpTemplateName    As String
End Type

Public typOpenFile As OPENFILENAME

Public Function RegParse(psStr As String, psPattern As String) As String

Dim oRegex As New RegExp
Dim sStr As String, sPattern As String

sStr2 = Replace(psStr, Chr(1), "", Compare:=vbBinaryCompare)
Debug.Print sStr2


sPattern = psPattern
    With oRegex
    .Global = True     'restricting regex to find only first match.
    .IgnoreCase = True  'ignoring cases while regex engine performs the search.
    .Pattern = sPattern

    If .Test(psStr) Then              'Testing if the pattern matches or not
        sStr = .Execute(psStr)(0)     'will provide the String which matches with Regex 
        sStr1 = .Replace(psStr, "$1") '.Replace function will replace the String with whatever is in the first set of braces - $X
    End If
End With

Exit_:

RegParse = sStr
Exit Function

Err_:
sStr = ""
gsMsg = Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description & Chr(13) & "Process aborted"
MsgBox gsMsg, vbCritical, "Error message"
GoTo Exit_

End Function


Public Function mfOpenFileDialog(psPathDir As String, Optional psFileCrit As String) As Boolean

Dim lReturn As Long
Dim strFilter As String
Dim sFileSelected As String
Dim bOk As Boolean

bOk = True

typOpenFile.lStructSize = Len(typOpenFile)
strFilter = "Text File (*" & psFileCrit & "*.csv)" & Chr(0) & "*" & psFileCrit & "*.csv" & Chr(0) '--> Define your filter here

With typOpenFile
    .lpstrFilter = strFilter
    .nFilterIndex = 1
    .lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
    .nMaxFile = Len(.lpstrFile) - 1
    .lpstrFileTitle = .lpstrFile
    .nMaxFileTitle = .nMaxFile
    .lpstrInitialDir = psPathDir
    .lpstrTitle = "My FileFilter Open"
    .flags = 0
End With

If GetOpenFileName(typOpenFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error message"
    bOk = False
End If

Exit_:

mfOpenFileDialog = bOk
Exit Function

Err_:

bOk = False
gsMsg = "Function mfOpenFileDialog" & Chr(13) & Err.Number & Chr(13) & Err.Description
MsgBox gsMsg, vbCritical, "Error message"
GoTo Exit_

End Function
```

I call mfOpenFileDialog function from a click button event

```
sPathDefault = "c:\Extraction"
sFileCrit = "rapport_"
If mfOpenFileDialog(sPathDefault, sFileCrit) = False Then GoTo Exit_
sPattern = "(^.*?(?=\x01))(\x01*)"
sFileName = RegParse(typOpenFile.lpstrFile, sPattern)
```

That's all